# How to control Android home button ? (Not only detect if home button is clicked)

Tags: android

We are implementing a restaurant ordering system. We have android tablet on the table for customer to place order. 
We permit customers to access only our app on the tablet. So the customer have to insert the password if they click Android home button to exit our app.

Does anyone knows how to control the home button on Android? (Not only detect if home button is clicked)

Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like what you really want is kiosk mode

Comment: You cannot control that in app since Android 4, but you can Pin app to lock the user on the app and ask for password to exit it. See [this](https://support.google.com/android/answer/6118421?hl=en)

Comment: @Kilarn123 Considered this solution, but it means every time launch app, admin should set it to lock. Thanks anyway

Comment: Thanks @EpicPandaForce . I am studying kiosk mode. https://developer.android.com/work/dpc/dedicated-devices/lock-task-mode#java